# (+) function in PLSQL

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I'm now dealing with PLSQL developer, which is my very first time. And I find this kind of query

```
select * from tableA, tableB
where tableA.field1 = tableB.field1(+)
```

I'm wondering the function of the `(+)` in the query. Could you guys be so kind to explain it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
where tableA.field1 = tableB.field1(+)
```

This is the old syntax for an outer join, adopted by Oracle, and made redundant when ANSI actually standardised the SQL language. Oracle themselves now suggest you use `outer join` in preference to this old syntax (from the link below):

> Oracle recommends that you use the `FROM` clause `OUTER JOIN` syntax rather than the Oracle join operator.

See [this entry in the Oracle docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries006.htm#sthref3175) for more detail.

Answer (score 4):

This is Oracle SQL OUTER JOIN syntax

It can be interpreted as

```
select * from tableA
OUTER JOIN tableB ON tableA.field1 = tableB.field1
```

Answer (score 2):

From the oracle documentation:

> (+)   Indicates that the preceding column is the outer join column in a join.

Answer (score 1):

It can be used as

```
select * from tableA right outer join tableB where tableA.field1 = tableB.field1
```

(+)operator indicates that it will return all the rows from the right table(matching and non matching) both rows from the right table. 
And matching rows are returned from the left table.
If rows are not matching from the right table then it returns null.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is used to retrive the mathced and unmached records from the table.

example:

table `A` and table `B`

if you are using like `A.column1=B.column1(+)`

it retrives the unmached records from table `A` and its called as left outer join.

Answer (score 0):

That's Oracle specific notation for a LEFT OUTER JOIN

Exemple :

```
select ...
from a,b
where a.id=b.id(+)
```

The query would be re-written

```
SELECT ...
     FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
```